# Navigation drawer and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my navigation drawer which is working fine. Now I created fragment:

```
public class LabourFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listViewLabour;
    private String[] resourcesList;


    public LabourFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //set adapter
        //TODO: change later to proper resource pull from server

        //have to use getActivity() as this is fragment and findViewById works from activity only

        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resourcesList));
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_labour, container, false);

    }


}
```

Now I am calling fragment from main activity:

```
public void selectItem(int position) {
    listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.drawerMenuList)[position]);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    //TODO: open proper acvtivity
    switch (position){ //positions reflects menu in drawer
        case 0:
            LabourFragment fragment = new LabourFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.mainContentFragment, fragment)
                    .commit();
            break;


    }
```

and get error message:

Error:(100, 25) error: no suitable method found for replace(int,LabourFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument LabourFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)

Tried cast LabourFragment to Fragment but no luck.
What I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: What does your activity extend and what are your imports for fragment

Comment: Its seems that you are using Fragment from support library and Fragment from the original source code

Comment: Guys thank you. So obvious now.